# How can I save the output on refresh : google Appscript

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have a requirement that on refresh the data should stay the same which we are calling from spreadsheet (data in spreadsheet can change due to which User view of his data should not change)
User first inputs his value, the value submits to the spreadsheet where there are some formulas which computes the data and gives the output in webapp.

Hence, if any other user is submitting input at the same time(from webapp) then It may change the output of the first user so we have to save the ouutput of the first user in another sheet which may work as data base. However How can I call the values from the data base and URL should remain the same with uniquue value like timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

In order to have your webapp updated, you should add an auto-refresh function in the JS file.

Example :

```
  function auto_check() {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(putData).askData();
    window.setTimeout(auto_check, 3000); // every 3sec
  }

  //function with returning values to update the webapp
  function putData(e) {
    $('#elem_to_update').html(e.new_value);
  }

  //in order to start the autocheck as soon as loaded
  window.onload = function () {
    auto_check();
  }
```

If this is not the result you need, please provide more infos of your issue